# gdb set breakpoint on exit function when main doesn't return 0

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'd like to examine the backtrace when main doesn't return 0. So i'd like to set a breakpoint on the exit function in that case. Ideally i'd put this in my `.gdbinit` file.

Comment: `break exit if $rax != 0` doesn't work?

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity, or do you want to find an actual bug in your application? I'm asking because the backtrace won't be very tantalizing once `main` has been left.